# How to Convert time in minutes:seconds format to just seconds?

Tags: r, dataframe

In my very large dataframe, I have time in the following minutes:seconds format:

```
Time          Period          
6:21          1
8:52          2
15:00         2
...
```

How can I make it so that the new time column reads only the total number of seconds in the time column?

```
Time          Period      Seconds    
6:21          1             381
8:52          2             532
15:00         2             900
```

Further, how could I make it so that the Seconds variable is multiplied by the Period Variable (to display the total number of seconds passed)?

```
Time          Period      Seconds     TimePassed
6:21          1             381         381
8:52          2             532         1064
15:00         2             900         1800
```

Comment: df$newtime<-with(df,Seconds*Period)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `period_to_seconds` after converting the Time column to `Period` class with `ms`.  Then, we multiply the 'Seconds' and 'Period' to create the 'TimePassed'

```
library(lubridate)
df1$Seconds <- period_to_seconds(ms(df1$Time))
df1$TimePassed <- df1$Seconds * df1$Period
```

-output

```
df1
#   Time Period Seconds TimePassed
#1  6:21      1     381        381
#2  8:52      2     532       1064
#3 15:00      2     900       1800
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Time = c("6:21", "8:52", "15:00"), Period = c(1L, 
2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```